# About Jordan-Chevalley decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

I have this problem:

Let $K$ be a field. Let $J\in M_n(K)$ a Jordan matrix. Prove that there exists a diagonal matrix $D$ and a nilpotent matrix $N$ such that $J=D+N$ and $DN=ND$.

I saw that this was similar to the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition, but this theorem is for every endomorphism. If I understood my problem, I only have to say that I can separate the diagonal matrix and the matrix with $1$ from the jordan block, and prove that the diagonal and the nilpotent matrix commute. Is that right, or I have to prove it like in jordan-chevalley decomposition?

Thank you!

Comment: Your idea is correct, you just take the natural choices for $D$ and $N$ and verify that they commute.